# How to add another one consumer?

Tags: c#, .net

How to add another one consumer in my program? I trying this, but not working...
I find this post [how to add consumers in multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686201/how-to-add-consumers-in-multithreading) , but its not what i need, becouse I dont need lock... And i need without class or something like that. Just with my code.. PLease help :)

```
private int occupiedBufferCount = 0;
    private int occupiedBufferCount2 = 0;
    int i = 0;
     private void Producer()
        {
            int how_much_numbers = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);            
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("random_skaiciai.txt"))
            {
                for (i = 0; i < how_much_numbers; i++)
                {  
                    Monitor.Enter(this);
                    if ((occupiedBufferCount == 1) || (occupiedBufferCount2 == 1))
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(this);
                    }
                    ++occupiedBufferCount;
                    buffer = i;
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    numbers = i;
                    //numbers = rnd.Next(nuo, iki);
                    writer.WriteLine(numbers + "");
                    prm = false;
                    fib = false;
                    Monitor.Pulse(this);
                    Monitor.Exit(this);
                    if (isCanceled == true)
                        break;
                }
                writer.Close();
                Set_p(kiek);
            }
    }
   private void Consumer1()
        {
            int how_much_numbers = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Primary_numbers.txt"))
            {
                    while (i < how_much_numbers)
                    {
                        Monitor.Enter(this);
                        if ((occupiedBufferCount == 0))
                        {
                            Monitor.Wait(this);
                        }
                        --occupiedBufferCount;
                        if (numbers != 0)
                            if (prime_num(numbers) == true)
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine(numbers + "");
                            }
                        prm = true;
                        Monitor.Pulse(this);

                        Monitor.Exit(this);

                        if (isCanceled == true)
                            break;
                }
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
     private void Consumer2()
        {
            int how_much_numbers = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("fibon_Numbers.txt"))
            {
                while (i < how_much_numbers)
                {
                    Monitor.Enter(this);
                    if ((occupiedBufferCount2 == 0))
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(this);
                    }
                    --occupiedBufferCount2;
                    if (numbers != 0)
                      if (isfibonaci(numbers) == true)
                         writer.WriteLine(numbers + "");
                    Monitor.Pulse(this);
                    Monitor.Exit(this);
                    if (isCanceled == true)
                        break;
                }
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You appear to be doing your CPU bound work in the UI thread.  You need to not do that.

Comment: I don't understand you? I think easy to solve this problem, becouse with one consumer working... But with other doesin't...:(